# Why we use null in sqlite methods?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Why we use null in sqlite database methods like:

```
db.insert("table1", null, cv);
```

Is it necessary use it in methods? 
Without null we have error.

Answer (score 3):

Read [**`insert`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

```
long insert (String table, 
                String nullColumnHack, 
                ContentValues values)
```

> **`String nullColumnHack`** : optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a
>   completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your
>   provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row
>   can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter
>   provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL
>   into in the case where your values is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a table named employee where all columns either allow NULL values or have defaults.

In some SQL implementations, this would be valid SQL:

INSERT INTO employee;

That's not valid in SQLite. You have to have at least one column specified:

INSERT INTO employee (somecol) VALUES (NULL);

Android and SQLite need some column that is safe to assign NULL to. If you have several such columns to choose from, pick one via the selection mechanism of your choice: roll of the dice, Magic 8-Ball(TM), coin flip, cubicle mate flip, etc.